# How do I setup Express to work with Backbone and pushState?

Tags: backbone.js, routes, express, middleware, pushstate

I am trying to setup Express to work with Backbone and pushState, but I'm not sure how to handle the routing. I've tried adding a middleware function (based on https://gist.github.com/3402977) to handle any undefined routes by inserting the `#` into the url, but it seems like the middleware is never getting called:

```
app.configure(function(){
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.favicon());
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(express.cookieParser('yadda yadda'));
  app.use(express.session());
  app.use(app.router);

  // This should handle undefined routes.
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next){
    // Isn't getting called.
    newUrl = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('Host') + '/#' + req.url;
    res.redirect(newUrl);
  });

  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});
```

Currently, whenever I visit an route that I don't define in Express (`http://localhost:3000/test/foo`), it gives me a `Could not GET /test/foo` error. I would like it to redirect to `http://localhost:3000/#/test/foo` so that Backbone can handle the routing for permalinks and whatnot. What am I missing?

Comment: did you find an answer to this?

Answer (score 1):

For future generations who land here:
The answer is that his middleware should be before the `app.use(app.router);` line.

Comment: After reading it again, its not so much middleware that you trying to make as much as a catch all route. This can be done using other methods such as `app.get("*", function () {} );` late in the router stack?